# How to fetch MySQL query by order with Multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hard to explain without using example. So this is how my MySQL database looks like:

table name: `general_info`

```
Movie_ID    Movie_Name
1           Iron Man
2           Superman
3           Batman
```

table name: `cast`

```
Movie_ID     Cast_Name              Cast_Rating
1            Robert Downey Jr.      90
1            Gwyneth Paltrow        45

2            Henry Cavill           75
2            Amy Adams              65

3            Christian Bale         90
3            Heath Ledger           95
```

table name: `Production_Companies`

```
Movie_ID       Production_name        Production_rating
1              Marvel                 95
1              Paramount              80

2              Legendary Pictures     65
2              DC Entertainment       75

3              Legendary Pictures     65
```

Now, I want to fetch movies like:

First add the rating of Ironman's top cast rating + Ironman's Top production company's rating and do this with each movie.

Like:

```
Iron man = 90 + 95 = 190 (Robert + Marvel)
SUperman = 75 + 75 = 150 (Henry + DC)
Batman = 95 + 65 = 160 (Christian + Legendary Pictures)
```

And fetch movies in this order:

```
Ironman
Batman
Superman
```

Now, Can I do this with pure MySQL or I need to use PHP also? Is my database structure right?

Comment: I assume if you want to use php you would use a bunch of SELECT statements and then print them out ;)

Comment: Yeah Razerz. But It will be not very effective. My database has 200k movies.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  How are you choosing the production names?  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: If you want to fetch all rows, you don't have to use 50 statements, you can use a couple, maximum 7, if I understood you correctly (which I think I did since you formatted your question properly) :)

Comment: why not Gwyneth, Amy and Heath in cast rating????

Comment: he wants to take the highest rating from cast, the highest rating Production company for each movie and add them together afaik

Comment: Yeah, exactly. other cast/production from the same movie has more rating.

Comment: @RAZERZ Can you give me some idea, how the query will look like? I am a bit confused.

Comment: You could join the two tables "cast" and "Production_Companies". Take the `MAX()` from "Cast_Rating" and "Production_Rating", get the `SUM()` from the two max values and then order the movies according to the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @rt:=0;
select movie_id, movie, cast_name as 'actor', cast_rating as 'rating', Production_name as 'company', Production_rating as 'prodrating', @rt:= ( cast_rating + Production_rating ) as 'sum' from(    
    select 
        c.`movie_id`,
        i.`movie_name` as `movie`,
        c.`Cast_Name`,
        c.`Cast_Rating`,
        p.`Production_name`,
        p.`Production_rating`
    from `cast` c
        left outer join `general_info` i on i.`movie_id`=c.`movie_id`
        join `production_companies` p on p.`movie_id`=c.`movie_id`
    order by `cast_rating` desc
) `sub`
group by `movie_id`
order by `sum` desc;
```

This outputs

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------------+-----+
| movie_id | movie    | actor             | rating | company            | prodrating | sum |
+----------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------------+-----+
|        1 | Iron Man | Robert Downey Jr. |     95 | Marvel             |  95        | 190 |
|        3 | Batman   | Heath Ledger      |     95 | Legendary Pictures |  65        | 160 |
|        2 | Superman | Henry Cavill      |     75 | DC Entertainment   |  75        | 150 |
+----------+----------+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------------+-----+
```

Or, rather than declare the variable using `set`, you can do it inline like this

```
select 
    @rt:=0 as 'x', 
    `movie_id`, 
    `movie`, 
    `cast_name` as 'actor', 
    `cast_rating` as 'rating', 
    `production_name` as 'company', 
    `production_rating` as 'prodrating', 
    @rt:= ( `cast_rating` + `production_rating` ) as 'overall-rating' 
    from (  
        select 
            c.`movie_id`,
            i.`movie_name` as `movie`,
            c.`cast_name`,
            c.`cast_rating`,
            p.`production_name`,
            p.`production_rating`
        from `cast` c
            left outer join `general_info` i on i.`movie_id`=c.`movie_id`
            join `production_companies` p on p.`movie_id`=c.`movie_id`
        order by `cast_rating` desc
    ) `sub`
group by `movie_id`
order by `overall-rating` desc;
```

Comment: It's likely I misunderstood the question but I interpreted the question to mean the top actor _ top production companies ratings should be summed for each movie - the above does just that but it differs from the example expected result for Batman. The highest rated actor is `Heath Ledger` not Christian Bale...

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in the question. Let me try out this. Sorry for the delay, internet went down.

Comment: One question, What is @rt:=0 ??

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right the thing, that you need is looks like this:

```
SELECT gi.Movie_Name, ((Select Cast_Rating 
FROM Cast as C 
where C.Movie_ID=gi.Movie_ID 
ORDER BY Cast_Rating desc 
LIMIT 1)+(SELECT Production_rating
 FROM Production_companies as PC 
where PC.Movie_ID=gi.Movie_ID 
ORDER BY Production_rating desc  
LIMIT 1)) as SummaryRating
    FROM general_info as gi 
    ORDER BY SummaryRating desc
```

it will actually calcalute and show everythis you said